# How to make a convolution layer which feeds from the local neighborhood of a staggered grid?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I'm new to keras, so maybe I'm simply missing an important point, but I was not able to specify a Conv2D layer, which would feed from a 2D staggered grid.

My staggered grid is defined as one 2D array of size (W, H) which holds the values for each cell center (let's call it "C") as well as one 2D array of size (W+1,H) which holds the values for the staggered vertical cell faces (let's call it "X") and one more 2D array of size (W,H+1) which holds the values for the staggered horizontal cell faces (let's call it "Y").

Now I want to create a Conv2D layer which takes the 3x3 neighborhood of "C" as well as the 4x3 neighborhood of "X" and the 3x4 neighborhood of "Y" (so I get all the data in the full 3x3 neighborhood, including the edges into my kernel). This should result in a layer output size of (W,H). Unfortunately all of my attempts have failed, because I can not feed multiple inputs into Conv2D, and also concatenating 3 independent Conv2D (one for "C", "X" and "Y") causes problems as they will not result in the same size.

Is there some way to accomplish this with keras ?